# Best OOP practice for accessing objects within objects across your project

Tags: java, oop, object

Okay so this has been an issue I keep running across. Now there are plenty of ways to do this, but I am wondering what you consider to be 'best practice'

Suppose we have  project structure as follows:

```
Java Project:
src/
   PackageA/
      ClassA.java
   PackageB/
      ClassB.java
      ClassC.java
   Main.java
```

Each class is as follows:

```
public class Main {
    private ClassA classA;
    private ClassB classB;
    public Main(){

    }

    public void runMainMethod(){
        //Init Objects
        classA = new ClassA();
        classB = new ClassB();

        classA.getDataFromClassC();
    }
}


public class ClassA {
    public ClassA(){

    }

    public void getDataFromClassC(){
        //Best way to get Data from classC?
    }
}


public class ClassB {
    private ClassC classC;
    public ClassB(){
        loadClassC();
    }
    private void loadClassC(){
        classC = new ClassC("ExampleName");
    }

}


public class ClassC {
    private String name;
    public ClassC(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getNam(){
        return name;
    }

}
```

I feel like passing Main through each class and creating a getter method in Main (for classB), and then another getter Method in B (for classC) is overkill.

Especially if it goes deeper. What if class C holds an object Class D? And I wanted to access class D from Class A?

Maybe I am not performing the best practice for OOP?

Any information on how you handle this, or a better practice would be greatly appreciated!

Question2:
What if, you only want one ClassB (Maybe because ClassC was loaded from a file, and multiple ClassB's will not be syncronized in respect to the class C).

Ex I want to avoid this issue:

```
ClassC classC = new ClassB().getClassC();
ClassC2 classC2 = new Class().getClassC();
classC.setName("C");
classC2.setName("C2);
```

where both classes have different name values

Comment: What you describe sounds like [Feature Envy](https://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell). See also [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: Classes should be self-contained and loosely coupled. You are describing composition (has it) relationship and there is nothing wrong with that.  If you need a class with one and only one instance, create Singleton.

Comment: You can create `classC` in `main ()` and pass it to both A and B afterwards. The recommended pure Java singleton implementation is an `enum` with a single element (Bloch, Effective Java).